# What is the easiest way to complete the clearance of the Hallow?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I just beat Skeleton Prime and unlocked the Steampunk (and Clentaminator), and I have the money to easily unlock Green Solution. However, I have a hard time getting world evils to 0% because I can't find the remaining Hallow until it grows and becomes hard to eliminate. How do I find the remaining Hallow to quickly convert to the Purity?

Answer (score 1):

The method recommended by the terraria wiki is probably what I would do. Dig hellevators  180 tiles apart in the general area of the Hallow, then jump down them and spray on both sides, that should get rid of all of the Hallow.